# WooCommerce: Call the Thankyou from my php file

Tags: woocommerce, payment-processing

I am new to WooCommerce. After the payment is made I am redirected to another PHP file (testpayresult.php). From this file, I need redirect to the Thankyou page in WooCommerce. How do I achieve this?

**Sending the order details to the payment gateway API:**

```
echo '<script src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId='. $responseData->id . '"></script>';
echo '<form action="/wp-content/plugins/woo-payment-gateway-for-taurus-datafast/testpayresult.php" class="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER AMEX DINER DISCOVER"> </form>';
echo '<form action="/wp-content/plugins/woo-payment-gateway-for-taurus-datafast/testpayresult.php" class="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER AMEX DINER DISCOVER"> </form>';
```

**The `testpayresult.php` file:**

```
<?php
echo "Payment Over";
echo "<br />POST<br />";
$resourcePath  = '/v1/checkout/' . $_GET["id"] . "/payment";  //$_GET["resourcePath"];
echo "<br /> Resource Path: " . $resourcePath;
$entityId  = $_GET["id"];
echo "<br /> Entity Id: " . $entityId;

//echo "<br /><br /> Thanks Page URL: " . get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' );
echo "<br />";

function check_transaction_status($presourcePath, $pentityId)
{
    $url = "https://test.oppwa.com" . $presourcePath;
    $url .= "?entityId=8ac7a4ca7402389d0174023e6b6b001c";
    
    echo "<br />URL: " . $url;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization:Bearer OGE4Mjk0MTg1YTY1YmY1ZTAxNWE2YzhjNzI4YzBkOTV8YmZxR3F3UTMyWA=='
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    // this should be set to true in production
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $responseData = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $responseData;
}

$response = check_transaction_status($resourcePath, $entityId);
```

Comment: To get WooCommerce thankyou page url for an order, requires at least the order Id…

Comment: How do I get the order Id in the testpayresultfile.php?

It is called by the submit in the generate_taurusdatafast_form($order) function in the wooshop-taurus-datafast.php file

Code in Github 
https://github.com/abrahamtaurus/datafast/blob/master/wooshop-taurus-datafast.php

Answer (score 0):

How do I get the order Id in the testpayresultfile.php?

It is called by the  submit in the generate_taurusdatafast_form($order) function in the wooshop-taurus-datafast.php file

[Code in Github](https://github.com/abrahamtaurus/datafast/blob/master/wooshop-taurus-datafast.php)